# Hudson: Builds of multi-module maven project fail, then immediately succeed again

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, hudson, multi-module

I have a multi-module project where the top level project serves both as the parent of the individual modules and as the project that declares the modules. Only this top level project is configured in Hudson (including automatic SVN checkout). The simplified layout is as follows:

```
ProjectRoot\
|
+---kernel\
|   |
|   +---pom.xml [ArtifactId=MyProject_kernel parent=MyProject]
|
+---model_foo\
|   |
|   +---pom.xml [ArtifactId=MyProject_model_foo, parent=MyProject]
|
+---pom.xml [ArtifactId=MyProject, parent=none]
```

Also, `model_foo` has a dependency on `kernel`.

Now, Hudson automatically discovers the `kernel` and `model_foo` sub projects, and it usually manages to build everything just fine.

However, each time I make a breaking change, such as create a new class in `kernel` and use it inside `model_foo`, I get a failing build for `model_foo`, followed by one that succeeds. The mail notifications are titled

- `Build failed in Hudson: MyProject » MyProject Model Foo #1545`
- `Hudson build is back to normal : MyProject » MyProject Model Foo #1546`

Why is that? I suspect it might have to do with the fact that the `MyProject` pom.xml is both the multi-module project and the parent of its modules, but before changing that I would like to know whether it's actually going to help.

I use Hudson 2.1.0.

### Update

This is the log of a failed build of the `web` module (equals `model_foo` in the diagram above). The build for the MyProject root project had the same build number, and succeeded.

I stripped out the actual compiler errors, which are exactly the same as if the newly introduced class was missing.

```
Started by upstream project "MyProject" build number 1545
Found mavenVersion 2.0.9 from file jar:file:/home/builder/opt/apache-maven-2.0.9/lib/maven-2.0.9-uber.jar!/META-INF/maven/org.apache.maven/maven-core/pom.properties
$ /home/builder/opt/jdk1.5.0_22//bin/java -Xmx1024m -Xms512m -cp /home/builder/var/hudson/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven-agent-2.1.0.jar:/home/builder/opt/apache-maven-2.0.9/boot/classworlds-1.1.jar hudson.maven.agent.Main /home/builder/opt/apache-maven-2.0.9 /home/builder/opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.24/webapps/hudson/WEB-INF/lib/hudson-remoting-2.1.0.jar /home/builder/var/hudson/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven-interceptor-2.1.0.jar 48555
<===[HUDSON REMOTING CAPACITY]===>   channel started
Executing Maven:  -N -B -f <http://ciserver:8080/hudson/job/MyProject/com.mycompany.myproject$web/ws/pom.xml> clean deploy -Dworkspace.path=/home/builder/var/hudson/jobs/MyProject/workspace/ -Droot.project.name=MyRoot -e
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MyProject
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, deploy]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean]
[INFO] Deleting directory <http://ciserver:8080/hudson/job/MyProject/com.mycompany.myproject$web/ws/target>
[INFO] [resources:resources]
[INFO] Using default encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [compiler:compile]
[INFO] Compiling 945 source files to <http://ciserver:8080/hudson/job/MyProject/com.mycompany.myproject$web/ws/target/classes>
[HUDSON] Archiving <http://ciserver:8080/hudson/job/MyProject/com.mycompany.myproject$web/ws/pom.xml> to /home/builder/var/hudson/jobs/MyProject/modules/com.mycompany.myproject$web/builds/2011-09-27_13-32-33/archive/com.mycompany.myproject/web/1.1-SNAPSHOT/pom.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure

{{{compiler failure here}}}


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:579)
    {{{stacktrace omitted}}}
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:516)
    {{{stacktrace omitted}}}
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 minute 7 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 27 13:33:42 CEST 2011 [INFO] Final Memory: 53M/508M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Which goals do you tell Maven to perform?

Comment: Maven simply performs `clean deploy`.

Comment: Would you be able to include above the log of the errors raised by Maven on a failed build? That would definitely help.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a rather untelling log. Just to be completely sure: is it possible that the CI server runs out of memory during the build? It says that up to 508 MB were allocated.

Comment: No, it does not run out of memory. It is as if it had not compiled the current version of the `kernel` module for some reason.

Comment: This is an error raised only when Maven is run from your integration server, right? Have you already (patiently) analysed the output of `mvn clean deploy -X`?